# Customize Google Apps menu

Tags: google-workspace

Is the Google Apps menu found on the top lefthand side of the screen at all customizable?  I'd like to remove links to Apps I don't use.

How can I add/remove menu items?

What other customization options are available?

Comment: Off topic:  Google home page is not a webapp.

Comment: @moioci - fair enough, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome you can use the [Google Gbar Editor](http://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hohfpabgkeokmaobfbfidibpodcegbgb) extension.

Comment: Google Gbar Editor No longer appears to exist.

Answer (score 1):

They refer to that internally as the Universal Navigation Bar.

No without writing your own instance / handler of the NVB you cannot.. If you work within a GAE project (google app engine) of your own creation you can do anything.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to explain the meaning of NVB and give some pointers on how can I write a custom instance/handler?

Comment: Paulo, this is pretty outdated - In reading my answer it's a bit misleading.  There is not a way to write a custom instance / handler that is associated across your google applications. This is if you were to implement a similar bar within your own apps (that you had written).  This was 3 years ago and I don't know if anything has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable unused app at Admin control panel.